# java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/jovyan/work/source/load-ivy.sc

Tags: scala, docker, chisel

I pulled the almondsh/almond from docker hub

run it using the command

**docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 almondsh/examples:latest**

when i creat a new Scala 3.12 file and try to run the following lines from chisel-bootcamp it gives me an error

**val path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/source/load-ivy.sc"
interp.load.module(ammonite.ops.Path(java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(path)))**

The ERROR message is

**java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/jovyan/work/source/load-ivy.sc**

I am new to docker chisel and Kindly help me resolve this problem so i be able to run the chisel examples from the chisel-bootcamp.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file is not present inside the docker image, then you need to mount a folder so that your application iside the container can access a folder on your host machine.

You can find useful information in the official documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: Look at the error message **/home/jovyan/work/source/load-ivy.sc** jupyter is searching for the files in the docker image user **jovyan** work directory do you mean I provide the files in that working directory through volumes

Comment: the issue has been resolved by providing the files in the exact directory as required through volumes thanks for the help